# To Run Counter strike

Tags: steam

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.I want to run counter-strike source,I went through similar questions on askubuntu which recommends to install steam .But when I tried to install steam through terminal it displayed this[image]

.Please guide me what to do now.

Comment: @Neil,getting exactly the same results with "sudo apt-get install steam-launcher"too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steam-launcher
```

then run `steam`

If that fails get the steam off the website

```
wget https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steam.deb
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

then run `steam`

Comment: Got same results with "sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install steam-launcher"

Comment: second command worked